# PushViewController does not work when called from App Delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate, pushviewcontroller

I have a tab-bar based app. When the app becomes active, I want it to go to the second tab bar (SecondViewController) and then, open DetailViewController.

Here's how I'm doing it:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

    SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [secondView openDetailView];
    [secondView release];
```

}

**SecondViewController.m**

```
-(void)openDetailView{
     NSLog(@"open detail view");

     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
            [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

openDetailView() does run (as I see the nslog working), but the DetailView does not get pushed? I know the code works because I have identical code in an IBAction which DOES push the detailView. The problem has something to do with it being called from the AppDelegate (or switching tabs).

So why doesn't the view get pushed when I call it from the App Delegate? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check if you are getting value of navigation controller by using following code -  UINavigationController *navController = [(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] navigationController];   also make sure if you are having some IBOutlet then those are connected properly.

Comment: `[self navigationController]` most likely is `nil` as the secondViewController is not assigned to any navigationController (at least from the code you are showing us.

Answer (score 0):

You push detailViewController to the Navigation-Stack of secondView, but secondView is in nowhere.

Try this...

```
SecondViewController *secondView ...

[self.tabBarController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];  <==

[secondView openDetailView];
```